# Thinking Sphinx in cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Rails 3, Thinking-sphinx 2.0.2 and Cucumber 0.10.2. I would like to test my thinking-sphinx search statements in my integration tests using Cucumber, but it seems very slow.

I've added to my env.rb file:

```
require 'cucumber/thinking_sphinx/external_world'
Cucumber::ThinkingSphinx::ExternalWorld.new

Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

As soon as I add these lines and run 'time rake cucumber' on a fresh project with no tests written yet it takes 48seconds (on a i7-930 with 12GB ram and an Intel SSD). If I take out the thinking_sphinx lines it takes 10 seconds.

Is this normal?
If so can I limit the loading of sphinx for anything with tag @slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you remove the last line (ie. set transactional fixtures back to true). The TS docs are a little out of date - refer to [my blog post instead](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/using_thinking_sphinx_with_cucumber).

That said, the second line could be the cause of the slowness - as it'll automatically configure, index and start Sphinx - and then stop it once the task is finished.

Comment: Taking out the second line does help with the speed. Now I'm faced with another problem, sphinx seems to be returning [nil] when testing: http://pastie.org/1702065 might create a new question for this.

Comment: I'm now using parallel_tests gem and this is quite fast so I'm not going to worry too much about this speed issue now.